React Native project created with npx using Kotlin instead of Java for Android files
I recently created a new React Native project using npx react-native init TestApp, but I noticed that the Android files in the project are using Kotlin (KT) extensions instead of Java (java). I expected the project to use Java files by default.
I am using visual studio code where i used its terminal to create the project!
Is there a specific configuration or setting that I missed during project creation? How can I ensure that new React Native projects start with Java files for Android development instead of Kotlin?
I appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving this issue. Thank you!
Here is an image of the project
React native project
I tried to change the settings inside the gradle file but I had no idea how to do it correctly

React Native template uses Kotlin since the version 0.73 https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/12/06/0.73-debugging-improvements-stable-symlinks#kotlin-template-on-android

When you create new projet, choose Empty Views Activity instead of Empty Activity in template..Refer attached image
Then on next screen, you will able to select programming langauge such as Java or Kotlin.
See second raw

Thank you so much, that worked perfectly! so the solution is to use Android studio instead of creating the project from the CLI!
